# useragent from txt file python

Tags: python, string

i would like my user agent to use diffrent agent on evry try i have txt file with all available agent strings i would to use them...... any idea ? in 2 word use agents randomly

```
    import sys
import random
import mechanize
import cookielib
import time
import random




i = 0
email = raw_input("# Enter Name : ")
passwordlist = raw_input ("# Pass List:")

useragents = (THIS IS MY PROBLEM HERE ) NO IDEA WHAT TO WRITE SO I CAN FETCH THEM FROM THE TXT FILE....

SOURCE_FILE='agents.txt'

def get():
    f = open(SOURCE_FILE)
    agents = f.readlines()

    return random.choice(agents).strip()

def getAll():
    f = open(SOURCE_FILE)
    agents = f.readlines()
    return [a.strip() for a in agents]

if __name__=='__main__':
    agents = getAll()
    for agent in agents:
        print agent
```

Comment: Aren't you already extracting them from the file in e.g. `getAll`?!

Comment: iam but any hint on how to make it get used by my script i mean i gotta put sth beside useragents =  but adding 1 string will eliminta to continue using other agents from the txt file isnt it ?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. You have already written functions to get either all agents or one random one; it's not clear why you can't just call one or both when you need them (as you do at the end of your script).

Comment: ok when i remove useragents = i get this error                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gg.py", line 103, in <module>
    check()
  File "gg.py", line 98, in check
    search()
  File "gg.py", line 64, in search
    attack(password.replace("\n",""))
  File "gg.py", line 42, in attack
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', random.choice(useragents))]
NameError: global name 'useragents' is not defined

Comment: So you're complaining that if you don't define `useragents`, you get an error because `useragents` isn't defined? What did you expect?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```
with open('useragents.txt') as f:
    useragents = [line.strip() for line in f]
...
```

Comment: THANKS !! exactly what i wass looking for :3 simple but i didnt think of it :v

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: One more question is there a way  i can put all my user agent inside my code without the need of txt file ?

Comment: a list? `['agent1','agent2', ...]`

Comment: @MADMIKE you should just use the `getAll()` function - it's already defined for you - there's no point in having the same functionality implemented in several places in your code.

Comment: yes a list but lets say they are 300 user agents i need to keep adding like this 'agent1','agent2', >?

Comment: @MADMIKE uhm.. yes? you should put each of them in a line for improved readibility.

Comment: ok thank you, before i mirro as answered...... i also would like to add a proxy to it ? no matter what i try it just dsnt work  even though proxy is working ;) ahaha last i will be asking BEST REGARDS

Comment: @MADMIKE Sorry but you should avoid asking other question in the comments in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback you need to set `useragents` to a list of possible user agent strings. These can be obtained by:

```
useragents = getAll()
```

This assumes that `useragents` is accessible to other parts of your code (you haven't shown), but your traceback indicates that this is probably the case.